# Install Laravel 4 with no root php 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

To install Laravel 4 I've to do some tricks because a don't have root PHP 5.3

Instead of using `php` I've to use: `/opt/php53/bin/`

So after downloading composer.phar I type:

`/opt/php53/bin/php ~/composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel`

Everything works fine until it gets to the json file line: `php artisan optimize`

Then a have to edit the json file and change all occurrences of `php` to `/opt/php53/bin/`
and the run

```
/opt/php53/bin/php ~/composer.phar update
```

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: get a new/better host?

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you on? You can create alias in linux or mac and add php to your path in windows. In either case you will have a better and short representation for the long path to php.

Comment: I think once you create the project on your local machine, you can then transfer it to your host. Don't expect such support in most of the shared hosting sites.